# Bubble Sort Shell, no output

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, bubble-sort

I'm having a problem where I am trying to use bubble sort in shell, I am not really sure where my problem is occurring as I am assuming that my sorting is correct. I am not getting an error but I am not sorting the numbers at all.

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( "$@" )
#echo ${array[@]} print all elements in the array

if [ $# -gt 9 ]
then
    echo Too many arguments, run the program over again
    exit
fi

j=0
flag=1
a=${#array[@]}

for((j=0;j < $a - 1 && flag==1 ;j++))
do
flag=0
for((i=0; i< $a-j-1; i++))
do
    x=${array[$i]}
    y=${array[$i+1]}
if ((x>y))
then
    flag=1
    export temp=$x 
    export x=$y 
    export y=$temp
fi
done
done

echo "Sorted Array: " ${array[@]}
```

Comment: A better place to start would be to use `PS4=':$LINENO+' bash -x yourscript` to observe runtime behavior with a log of every command executed, figure out the first place where the script isn't doing what you expect, and write a narrower question that only reflects that one isolated piece of unexpected behavior on the part of the shell, rather than (effectively) asking people to debug your script for you.

Comment: BTW, what's with the `export`s?

Comment: No part of your script modifies `array`.

Comment: You know that there is `sort`, so it is just for fun, right?

Comment: You compare `x` and `y`, not `$x` and  `$y`, and you do not put the swapped values back into the array. And I am not sure about your `if` syntax – I would use `if [ … ]`.

Comment: @Renardo The `if ((x>y))` part is correct. Note the double parentheses.

Comment: @Socowi: Certainly you are right – but with the double parentheses my `bash` never enters the `then` branch. With `if [ $x > $y ]` it does. Version problem?

Comment: @Renardo, `if [ $x > $y ]` does a completely different thing, not related to what the OP wants to accomplish. In that context, `>` is a redirection operator, not a comparison. It's precisely equivalent to `if [ $x ] > $y` (which itself has poorly-defined behavior due to the inadequate quoting).

Comment: @Renardo, and even if it *were* a comparison, as in `if [[ $x > $y ]]`, that's a lexicographic comparison, not a numeric one, so it improperly thinks that `9` is larger than `10` (since `9` sorts after `1`).

Comment: @Renardo I cannot give you a guarantee, but it is probably not a version problem. I tested `if ((x>y))` successfully in bash 3.2.57(2) and 4.3.48(1). If you are curious, open another question with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you swap the variables `x` and `y` but never any array entries. Instead of

```
x=${array[$i]}
y=${array[$i+1]}
if ((x>y)); then
    flag=1
    export temp=$x 
    export x=$y 
    export y=$temp
fi
```

write

```
x=${array[$i]}
y=${array[$i+1]}
if ((x>y)); then
    flag=1
    array[$i]="$y"
    array[$i+1]="$x"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even notice this. This solved my problem